# How Do I print this box with a function?

Tags: python, printing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/glt4M.png really confused on how this works, if I formatted something wrong in this post my bad.

Comment: If you mean how would you *write* a function to print this box: the same way as without a function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to print in console, try this:

```
def printBox():
  print("+-----+")
  print("|     |")
  print("|     |")
  print("+-----+")

printBox()
```

Comment: "with a function"?

Answer (score 1):

```
print("""
+----------+
|          |
|          |
+----------+
""")
```

so simple as that.

Comment: put the print statement within a function or as a return string

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary cases, it may be best to define the width of the box:

```
def box(w):
    final_box = ['+{}+'.format('-'*w) if i == 0 or i == w-2 else "|{}|".format(' '*(w)) for i in range(w-1)]
    for i in final_box:
        print i
box(5)
```

Output:

```
 +-----+
 |     |
 |     |
 +-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make a variable could be good:

```
>>> box = "+----+\n|     |\n|     |\n+----+"
>>> print(box)
+----+
|    |
|    |
+----+
```

Or a function:

```
>>> def box(w, h):
...     head = '+' + '-'*w*2 + '+'
...     body = '|' + ' '*w*2 + '|'
...     box = head + '\n' + (body + '\n') * h + head
....    return box
>>> print(box(2, 2))
+----+
|    |
|    |
+----+
```